# Let $C$ be a finite-dimensional convex subset of a normed space. Then the convex function $f: C \to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $\operatorname{ri}(C)$

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces, convex-analysis

I'm trying to solve below question (*Corollary 0.5.*) in [this](http://www.mat.unimi.it/users/libor/AnConvessa/continuity.pdf) lecture note.

> Let $C$ be a finite-dimensional convex set in a normed vector space $X$. Then every convex function $f: C \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $\operatorname{ri}(C)$ (the relative interior of $C$).

Could you have a check if I understand the concept of subspace topology properly?

---

**Proof:**

Let $A$ be the smallest affine subspace containing $C$, i.e., $A := \operatorname{aff} (C)$. Then $A = V+a$ for some vector subspace $V$ of $X$ and $a\in X$. Then $n:=\dim V$ is finite, and $\operatorname{ri}(C)$ the interior of $C$ w.r.t. the subspace topology of $A$.

Let $C' :=C -a$. Then $\operatorname{aff}(C') = \operatorname{aff}(C) -a =V$ and $\operatorname{ri}(C') = \operatorname{ri}(C) -a$.  We define $g:C' \to \mathbb R$ by $g(x) :=f(x+a)$. Clearly, $\operatorname{ri}(C')$ is convex and open in $V$. On the other hand, $V$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^{n}$. Hence $g$ is continuous in the subspace topology of $V$. This implies $g$ is continuous in the topology of $X$. Hence $f$ is continuous in the topology of $X$.